# NPM pre hook not working in package.json file?

Tags: npm, jestjs, npm-scripts, supertest

I'm writing e2e tests with Supertest for my NestJS application and in my package.json file, I have the command "test:e2e" which runs my e2e tests. I also have a pre- hook (called "pretest:e2e") which essentially tears down and creates a new docker container (using nerdctl) for the tests each time the tests are ran. However, whenever I run my tests, the "pretest:e2e" hook doesn't run and I can't seem to figure out why. I've pasted the scripts from my package.json file below:

```
"db:test:rm": "nerdctl compose down",
"db:test:up": "nerdctl compose up",
"db:test:restart": "yarn db:test:rm && yarn db:test:up",
"pretest:e2e": "yarn db:test:restart",
"test:e2e": "dotenv -e .env.test -- jest --no-cache --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
```

Environment:

- macOS v12.6.1
- Node v18.12.1
- NPM v8.19.2

I was able to verify that the commands "db:test:restart", "db:test:rm", and "db:test":up" all work as expected, but I can't seem to figure out why the pre- hook isn't running. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I see in the scripts that you are using `yarn` and these script hooks are fully functioning using `npm`, `yarn` only supports some of these hooks like `prepack`, `prepublish` but not any custom `pre<script>` as per their [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts/):

> In particular, we intentionally don't support arbitrary pre and post hooks for user-defined scripts (such as prestart). This behavior, inherited from npm, caused scripts to be implicit rather than explicit, obfuscating the execution flow. It also led to surprising executions with yarn serve also running yarn preserve.

So you can either switch to use `npm` or chain your scripts using `&&` like:

```
"test:e2e": "dotenv -e .env.test -- yarn pretest:e2e && jest --no-cache --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
```